# Does Parallel.Invoke in .NET work efficiently for millions of delegates?

Tags: c#, .net

In C #12 in a nutshell, there was this claim.

"Parallel.Invoke still works efficiently if you pass in an array of a million delegates.
This is because it partitions large numbers of elements into batches that it assigns to a handful of underlying Tasks rather than creating a separate Task for each delegate."

Is there any evidence from Microsoft learn documentation or is it a claim from author after verifying it?

Comment: Its in the reference source: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs#L278 and https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L6725

Comment: @user1937198 Keep in mind that the reference source is specifically for .NET Framework.  For .NET, [there's a few differences](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs#L191) (but none that really matter here).